# Possible to test iPhone app without a real device?

Tags: iphone, ios, testing

I have to convert an iPhone app which is published at the AppStore. However, I do not have iPhone.
Is there any way to test the functionality of this app without a real phone? Would the emulator be of any help? Or maybe some web application?

Comment: Thanks all, although I was hoping that some web app exists which could install apps from AppStore and let us test it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't have the source code for the app, you can't run it without an iPhone or iPod touch.

The iPhone Simulator (included with the SDK) won't be of any help, because it only runs apps that are compiled for Intel (your Mac). It's not an emulator and cannot run apps that are compiled for actual devices (ARM processors). Without the source code, you can't recompile the app.

Answer (score 7):

iOS Simulator is ***NOT*** an emulator. It's a simulator. It doesn't emulate iOS hardware, it is running your app compiled as 64bit Intel app for Mac and displays it inside the iPhone-like window that looks and feels like iPhone, but doesn't have all features and some things don't work the same way.

For example, iOS has a case-sensitive file system, Mac doesn't, so iOS Simulator doesn't either. Also, there's no camera, sms, compass, accelerometer, magnetometer, or any other iPhone-specific feature.

So, yes, you can test some apps using iOS Simulator, but no, you shouldn't test them *only* using iOS Simulator.

Answer (score 3):

You can of course test the app just with the simulator. However, the simulator lacks some capabilities like accelerometer data, so if you plan on using anything like this, you should consider getting at least the cheapest iPod Touch for testing.
If you do any operations that use lots of rescources (memory, processing power) you need to consider that the iPhone is not as fast as your Mac either.